# Fullcalendar modify width events

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, codepen

Need a help, I need width of events  modify like this event width
[image: now]
[image: then]

when see day view April 12, 2018

```
`https://codepen.io/tonythanh/pen/ZoeMmY?editors=0010`
`http://jsfiddle.net/quigleydbillyp/h30jkpuj/2/`
```

PS: can i set all events same width?

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried?

Comment: As @Codeer said, what have you tried? what isn't working? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to ask a good question.

Comment: just updated @Codeer

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *within the question itself*. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your question and elaborate a bit on what isn't working. What behavior are you getting instead of the expected behavior? Please refer to the link Rory posted to create a good question because I have a hard time following you.

Comment: thank for read, @Codeer, update images 1-now, 2-3 what i want.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired behaviour by adding `slotEventOverlap` and set this to `false`. This will disallow for the events to overlap.

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },

         events: [
        {
            title  : 'event1',
            start  : '2018-05-01 02:30:00'
        },
        {
            title  : 'event2',
            start  : '2018-05-01',end : '2018-05-01 03:00:00'
        },
        {
            title  : 'event3',
            start  : '2018-05-15'
        }
    ],
    slotEventOverlap: false,
    eventRender: function (event, element, view) { 
        // event.start is already a moment.js object
        // we can apply .format()
        var dateString = event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD");

        $(view.el[0]).find('.fc-day[data-date=' + dateString + ']').css('background-color', '#FAA732');
     }

});
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h30jkpuj/3/)

You can find a bit more detailed information in the fullCalendar [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotEventOverlap)

Comment: hi, thank for help, can you help me make this  a datepicker https://imgur.com/a/eyyRH3v and when i change date on this datepicker call change full calendar to datepicked , @Codeer

Comment: No sorry, that is not captured in the question. I just answered the question. @karonrenta

Comment: hi @Codeer can yu modify all width of event same size?

Comment: @karonrenta What do you mean? The width is same size if you place them next to one another?

Comment: @karonrenta The event width is already rendered when events overlap for them to be the same width.

Comment: @karonrenta I have not enough experience to know if it is possible. I only knew the answer to your initial question.